# How to search an Object for a given string php

Tags: php

I am trying to create a simple php search for my site.
I want to search through an object for part of a string.

```
$string_to_find = "hello";
```

And here is the object

```
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[1]
      public 'id' => int 1
      public 'name' => string 'John is hello'

  1 => 
    object(stdClass)[2]
      public 'id' => int 2
      public 'name' => string 'Hello people'
  2 => 
    object(stdClass)[2]
      public 'id' => int 3
      public 'name' => string 'yes people'
```

How can I go iterate through this object and return an object with values(name) of "hello". It shouldn't be case sensitive.

So if it works , the 0 and 1 objs should be the expected behavior?

I tried something like this :

```
$arr = array(); 
foreach($filesPopular as $k=>$v) { 
  if(strpos($string_to_find, $v)) {
      $arr[$k] = $v;
      $fileslike =  $arr[$k];
  }
}
```

Error: Object could not be converted to int"

Comment: you could just use a `foreach` and an `if`, it'll work just fine, use an `stripos` if its meant not to be case sensitive

Comment: @Ghost any sample code on how to achieve that?

Comment: you could just try it, won't take you 50 lines to do it, a foreach, an if comparison, and maybe an unset or a new assignment to a new container

Comment: @Ghost I tried foreach, can u check my edit if u have any input...

Comment: Are you, by chance, getting this array of objects from a call to [`json_decode`](http://php.net/json_decode)?

Answer (score 1):

Just like in the comments, just use a `foreach` and an `if`.

Use `stripos` so that it doesn't take it case sensitive. Make sure that you use strict comparisons `!== false`, you'll get false positives if `stripos` returns `0` (since zero is considered found):

Idea:

```
$string_to_find = "hello";
$contains_the_string = array(); // container of the matches
foreach ($filesPopular as $k => $v) { // so, for each object
    if (stripos($v->name, $string_to_find) !== false) {
    // check if string to find is contained within the name attribute
        $contains_the_string[] = $v; // if yes, put it inside the container
    }
} 
print_r($contains_the_string);
```

Comment: How about if I have a string like $string_to_find = "hello well"; and some value has name value of "Hello James is a good.." ,  How can I still get the given object. The answer u gave me works well only if the value is explicitly the same.

Comment: @ObasiObenyOj you'll need to cut the words (or should i say explode by spaces), make a foreach of each words and iterate through the object, very inefficient though, and thats why we have a thing called databases

Comment: @ObasiObenyOj with this code, you should still get the given object. Make sure you're using the `!== false` instead of what you had in the if statement before.